# what is the best replacement for TabPages

Tags: c#, winforms

if one part of one form of our app has many views - let's say depending on a radio button selection some where else on that form - then sometimes using a TabControl with some tabPages can be easy and helpful to show different views based on that selection.
so I still would like to have that "multiple views" functionality but I do not want to use a TabPage.... what would be the best replacement for that?

Comment: **With no prejudice to [ho1](http://stackoverflow.com/users/306651/ho1).** I honestly don't understand you. If it was an answer like [ho1's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608970/what-is-the-best-replacement-for-tabpages/3609012#3609012) you wanted, you shouldn't have bothered asking the question because anyone could have told you to do exactly as he said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have a `Panel` or something to define the area and then you could create one User control for each "view" that you want and then when the user selects a different radio button you just shows/hides the relevant user controls inside that `Panel`.

Or if the "views" are very simple, maybe the User controls would be overkill and you could just have a `GroupBox` for each view that you show/hide, but that can quickly create messy code if there are lots of event handlers etc.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you'll have to code such a control yourself if you desire a lot of functionality. For regular operations, however, you can use this control I found on CodeProject: [Multipane Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/multipane_control.aspx).